# SurveyMonkey API v3 language codes

Tags: surveymonkey

For API v2 there was a table which related language_id (integer) to language description which I built into my app so that I could match my user language to that of the survey.

Is there a similar table for v3 to relate language (string) to the language description; I couldn't find one.

It would be good to know what language codes are currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

In V2 survey showed language_id which was an internal number that references a language, the table is located [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/overview/data-types/).

In V3 the language used is the standard ISO language codes used everywhere (instead of a number it'll be `en`, `es`, `fr` for example. [Here's a table](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm) of language codes I just searched up. Maybe a similar table should be added to the API v3 docs.

Comment: Thank you - it *would* be useful to know what codes are likely to occur so please add to the documentation.
I presume that you don't distinguish between different types of English since I have seen "en" whereas you might distinguish between different types of Chinese, as you did in the language_id in v2.

Answer (score 0):

```
survey_languages = [
    {"name": "English", "id": 1, "code": "en"},
    {"name": "Albanian", "id": 24, "code": "sq"},
    {"name": "Arabic", "id": 25, "code": "ar"},
    {"name": "Armenian", "id": 26, "code": "hy"},
    {"name": "Basque", "id": 27, "code": "eu"},
    {"name": "Bengali", "id": 28, "code": "bn"},
    {"name": "Bosnian", "id": 29, "code": "bs"},
    {"name": "Bulgarian", "id": 30, "code": "bg"},
    {"name": "Catalan", "id": 31, "code": "ca"},
    {"name": "Chinese (Simplified)", "id": 2, "code": "zh-cn"},
    {"name": "Chinese (Traditional)", "id": 3, "code": "zh-tw"},
    {"name": "Portuguese (Brazilian)", "id": 17, "code": "pt-br"},
    {"name": "Portuguese (Iberian)", "id": 16, "code": "pt"},
    {"name": "Croatian", "id": 32, "code": "hr"},
    {"name": "Czech", "id": 33, "code": "cs"},
    {"name": "Danish", "id": 4, "code": "da"},
    {"name": "Dutch", "id": 5, "code": "nl"},
    {"name": "Estonian", "id": 34, "code": "et"},
    {"name": "Filipino", "id": 35, "code": "tl"},
    {"name": "Finnish", "id": 6, "code": "fi"},
    {"name": "French", "id": 7, "code": "fr"},
    {"name": "Georgian", "id": 36, "code": "ka"},
    {"name": "German", "id": 8, "code": "de"},
    {"name": "Greek", "id": 9, "code": "el"},
    {"name": "Hebrew", "id": 37, "code": "he"},
    {"name": "Hindi", "id": 38, "code": "hi"},
    {"name": "Hungarian", "id": 39, "code": "hu"},
    {"name": "Icelandic", "id": 40, "code": "is"},
    {"name": "Indonesian", "id": 41, "code": "id"},
    {"name": "Irish", "id": 42, "code": "ga"},
    {"name": "Italian", "id": 10, "code": "it"},
    {"name": "Japanese", "id": 11, "code": "ja"},
    {"name": "Korean", "id": 12, "code": "ko"},
    {"name": "Kurdish", "id": 43, "code": "ku"},
    {"name": "Latvian", "id": 44, "code": "lv"},
    {"name": "Lithuanian", "id": 45, "code": "lt"},
    {"name": "Macedonian", "id": 46, "code": "mk"},
    {"name": "Malay", "id": 13, "code": "ms"},
    {"name": "Malayalam", "id": 47, "code": "ml"},
    {"name": "Norwegian", "id": 14, "code": "no"},
    {"name": "Persian", "id": 48, "code": "fa"},
    {"name": "Polish", "id": 15, "code": "pl"},
    {"name": "Punjabi", "id": 49, "code": "pa"},
    {"name": "Romanian", "id": 50, "code": "ro"},
    {"name": "Russian", "id": 18, "code": "ru"},
    {"name": "Serbian", "id": 51, "code": "sr"},
    {"name": "Slovak", "id": 52, "code": "sk"},
    {"name": "Slovenian", "id": 53, "code": "sl"},
    {"name": "Spanish", "id": 19, "code": "es"},
    {"name": "Swahili", "id": 54, "code": "sw"},
    {"name": "Swedish", "id": 20, "code": "sv"},
    {"name": "Tamil", "id": 55, "code": "ta"},
    {"name": "Telugu", "id": 56, "code": "te"},
    {"name": "Thai", "id": 57, "code": "th"},
    {"name": "Turkish", "id": 21, "code": "tr"},
    {"name": "Ukrainian", "id": 22, "code": "uk"},
    {"name": "Vietnamese", "id": 58, "code": "vi"},
    {"name": "Welsh", "id": 59, "code": "cy"},
]
```